# ¿Error al serializar cadena XML en objeto clase C#?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core

Desde un archivo XML  construí la clase .cs que genera  con Xml2CSharp, ahora trato de leer ese mismo archivo y deserializarlo en la clase objeto y me devuelve error :

*Error en el documento XML (1, 56).
InnerException = {"No se esperaba ."}*

```
C#

   }
        public Colombia XML(string xml, out string Error)
        {
            Colombia comprobante = new Colombia();

            Error = "";
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Colombia));
                StringReader sXML = new StringReader(xml);
                comprobante = (Colombia)serializer.Deserialize(sXML);// AQUI EL ERROR

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error = "Error en la Serialización" + ex.Message;
                comprobante = new Colombia();
            }
            return comprobante;

        }
```

archivo .Xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
     xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" 
     xmlns:sac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" 
     xmlns:sbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2"
      xmlns:sig="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2" 
      xmlns:sts="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:Structures-2-1" 
      xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" 
      xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" 
      xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
          <ext:ExtensionContent>
            <sts:DianExtensions>
              <sts:InvoiceControl>
                <sts:InvoiceAuthorization>18764013334344</sts:InvoiceAuthorization>
                <sts:AuthorizationPeriod>
                  <cbc:StartDate>2021-05-18</cbc:StartDate>
                  <cbc:EndDate>2022-05-18</cbc:EndDate>
                </sts:AuthorizationPeriod>
                <sts:AuthorizedInvoices>
                  <sts:Prefix>FEL</sts:Prefix>
                  <sts:From>12001</sts:From>
                  <sts:To>20000</sts:To>
                </sts:AuthorizedInvoices>
              </sts:InvoiceControl>
              <sts:InvoiceSource>
                <cbc:IdentificationCode listAgencyID="6" listAgencyName="United Nations Economic Commission for Europe" listSchemeURI="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:codelist:gc:CountryIdentificationCode-2.1">CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
              </sts:InvoiceSource>
              <sts:SoftwareProvider>
                <sts:ProviderID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="6" schemeName="31">900390126</sts:ProviderID>
                <sts:SoftwareID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">82d21092-144e-4b66-b720-6cdf9f661767</sts:SoftwareID>
              </sts:SoftwareProvider>
              <sts:SoftwareSecurityCode schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">2c41d4a24fbc8e57449681b644a5c89773face3b5868a2a13d13be4a1d722ed9c3b0e59481cc0059f47a835feafb2d77</sts:SoftwareSecurityCode>
              <sts:AuthorizationProvider>
                <sts:AuthorizationProviderID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="4" schemeName="31">800197268</sts:AuthorizationProviderID>
              </sts:AuthorizationProvider>
              <sts:QRCode>NumFac: FEL12657
    FecFac: 2021-06-04
    HorFac: 16:17:28-05:00
    NitFac: 830026664
    DocAdq: 1071630658
    ValFac: 1110006.00
    ValIva: 0.00
    ValOtroIm: 0.00
    ValTolFac: 1110006.00
    CUFE: fa9cd55ef618e1f5c78957578548121d7bf5167be813860af697cb0f22d67c1d3938a9719a41158d36bda4fb3207b8f5
    https://catalogo-vpfe.dian.gov.co/document/searchqr?documentkey=fa9cd55ef618e1f5c78957578548121d7bf5167be813860af697cb0f22d67c1d3938a9719a41158d36bda4fb3207b8f5</sts:QRCode>
            </sts:DianExtensions>
          </ext:ExtensionContent>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
      <ext:UBLExtension><ext:ExtensionContent><ds:Signature Id="xmldsig-038f48f4-b7d6-48fb-abc3-7f2f3191726e">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-038f48f4-b7d6-48fb-abc3-7f2f3191726e-ref0" URI="">
    <ds:Transforms>
    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>2yK9owU688cwLrK6uHgyxHRU32VQjaE6SMh7Do03uxI=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
    <ds:Reference URI="#xmldsig-038f48f4-b7d6-48fb-abc3-7f2f3191726e-keyinfo">
    <ds:Transforms>
    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>v9qBljC3sy2fjuOqZT9qd/jrGBWOfOoBtRPEDbSZcAg=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
    <ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-038f48f4-b7d6-48fb-abc3-7f2f3191726e-signedprops">
    <ds:Transforms>
    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>TEXRLwuiH/Lnm+GyP8CLHja/kgfE2ym/GkaBfchMIUw=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-038f48f4-b7d6-48fb-abc3-7f2f3191726e-sigvalue">
    1UjE5UiUKZGKeCLBeBuunRsTsqQugkX/cvlDQXfVcVlMhts8yksZYWOJLxuh6c4OxIJfnLSS0ocA
    oteEzsn0gVOxjg3s1o4N9jG2IQdj3VRp1UXA2exSBMC91GU0zot1RJJE+r5ViVBfRhN3XcGm9ra9
    39YG+uV9yumo8PSHorY29O1bzfs+3vp1PQGgRfJKiYorYqFo9ejgfDp7Dkv16AhLdf8ugitsrpeA
    9f/opBLykGan7uGkYVbUNHf+waUOINKwSrewNlKw7FhVqobyQI25ZMRR8v78/N8yw7grgEaVS+dJ
    ttUW9nBP/gNBDBjZsj+1xeDiUeLcSLuFvpApUg==
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo Id="xmldsig-038f48f4-b7d6-48fb-abc3-7f2f3191726e-keyinfo">
    <ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>
    0KzzEPGgM8bcHmNn0x/1AUk4o7eEcJq0osz/fnM8P
    fihJl6HCc8mWTtGXmLTNEjn+HxtqJQSfeFQaygNazsTwB7pQU/amX4xQuLnwrIRFX6xZ3PIdLDKn
    6+HfyCNYOdTKwXVbWnLbw7vKKUh/nQzZRLL6D54l/BJpG1lNJ40Q+5hYsOrh3V393hTclMLypu3h
    VSgujO3MRWnIIdFXMUiFczKSUYayi4eW0WGu6arUkwXwwc48fdJ+zrgd2PV+04rxejicQWQOK/3r
    Ago+sYrlVAgfvcPDGJSKJlUlFY5xQ39uGn0l4TcLsn9Qf8rrYIOQbdlHr3fqn91B9BkMSO1hBjJ9
    RWBZoOLfnmtuSyWCV/OsdukEi6XL7Dwcm7WCkugTjvPYvgAaX44MECx1QZ3Vu08465B7ZVn9mFjm
    jh6p77KCnreeds3ZDwkgPW9zM5I+xORCDyS4k8mEYwxnMYe0Z0ew3IopU5aXHG8WfreokGofqDVF
    1LRMd7E0E85F6EqxoJdmdCs2DSWXKypgM1d0qs27zKJoFo/gKQeRlJQ0DN4tOVb9gZIA4p4beJ4=
    </ds:X509Certificate>
    <ds:X509SubjectName>C=CO,ST=CUNDINAMARCA,L=COTA,O=JOSE ALEJANDRO FRANCO RUEDA,OU=Emitido por Andes SCD Ac 26 69C 03 Torre B Of 701,T=Emisor Factura Electronica - Persona Juridica,SERIALNUMBER=8300266644,CN=VETIPLUS S.A.,EMAILADDRESS=alejandro.franco@vetiplus.com,STREET=AV. CL 80 VIA BOGOTA-COTA KM 1.5 ENT. PARQUE LA FLORIDA TERRAPUERTO BODEGA 9</ds:X509SubjectName>
    <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
    <ds:X509IssuerName>C=CO,L=Bogota D.C.,O=Andes SCD,OU=Division de certificacion entidad final,CN=CA ANDES SCD S.A. Clase II v2,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1614696e666f40616e6465737363642e636f6d2e636f</ds:X509IssuerName>
    <ds:X509SerialNumber>945118941815015897</ds:X509SerialNumber>
    </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
    </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties Target="#xmldsig-038f48f4-b7d6-48fb-abc3-7f2f3191726e"><xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-038f48f4-b7d6-48fb-abc3-7f2f3191726e-signedprops"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2021-06-04T16:12:53.816-05:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>L+964bg7DBr68qOBo+hpWAAvOYNSUjoR0BzPld9+N1M=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>C=CO,L=Bogota D.C.,O=Andes SCD,OU=Division de certificacion entidad final,CN=CA ANDES SCD S.A. Clase II v2,1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1614696e666f40616e6465737363642e636f6d2e636f</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>945118941815015897</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate><xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier><xades:SignaturePolicyId><xades:SigPolicyId><xades:Identifier>https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/politicadefirma/v2/politicadefirmav2.pdf</xades:Identifier><xades:Description>Política de firma para facturas electrónicas de la República de Colombia</xades:Description></xades:SigPolicyId><xades:SigPolicyHash><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>dMoMvtcG5aIzgYo0tIsSQeVJBDnUnfSOfBpxXrmor0Y=</ds:DigestValue></xades:SigPolicyHash></xades:SignaturePolicyId></xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier></xades:SignedSignatureProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object>
    </ds:Signature></ext:ExtensionContent></ext:UBLExtension></ext:UBLExtensions>
      <cbc:UBLVersionID>UBL 2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
      <cbc:CustomizationID>10</cbc:CustomizationID>
      <cbc:ProfileID>DIAN 2.1</cbc:ProfileID>
      <cbc:ProfileExecutionID>1</cbc:ProfileExecutionID>
      <cbc:ID>FEL12657</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:UUID schemeID="1" schemeName="CUFE-SHA384">fa9cd55ef618e1f5c78957578548121d7bf5167be813860af697cb0f22d67c1d3938a9719a41158d36bda4fb3207b8f5</cbc:UUID>
      <cbc:IssueDate>2021-06-04</cbc:IssueDate>
      <cbc:IssueTime>16:17:28-05:00</cbc:IssueTime>
      <cbc:DueDate>2021-07-04</cbc:DueDate>
      <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>01</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
      <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>COP</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
      <cbc:LineCountNumeric>2</cbc:LineCountNumeric>
      <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cbc:AdditionalAccountID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeID="4" schemeName="31">1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
        <cac:Party>
          <cbc:IndustryClassificationCode>4620</cbc:IndustryClassificationCode>
          <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>VETIPLUS S. A.</cbc:Name>
          </cac:PartyName>
          <cac:PhysicalLocation>
            <cac:Address>
              <cbc:ID>11001</cbc:ID>
              <cbc:CityName>BOGOTÁ, D.C.</cbc:CityName>
              <cbc:PostalZone>111061</cbc:PostalZone>
              <cbc:CountrySubentity>Bogotá</cbc:CountrySubentity>
              <cbc:CountrySubentityCode>11</cbc:CountrySubentityCode>
              <cac:AddressLine>
                <cbc:Line>CALLE 1</cbc:Line>
              </cac:AddressLine>
              <cac:Country>
                <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                <cbc:Name languageID="es">Colombia</cbc:Name>
              </cac:Country>
            </cac:Address>
          </cac:PhysicalLocation>
          <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>VETIPLUS S. A.</cbc:RegistrationName>
            <cbc:CompanyID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="4" schemeName="31">830026664</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cbc:TaxLevelCode listName="05">O-23;R-99-PN</cbc:TaxLevelCode>
            <cac:RegistrationAddress>
              <cbc:ID>25214</cbc:ID>
              <cbc:CityName>COTA</cbc:CityName>
              <cbc:PostalZone>250010</cbc:PostalZone>
              <cbc:CountrySubentity>Cundinamarca</cbc:CountrySubentity>
              <cbc:CountrySubentityCode>25</cbc:CountrySubentityCode>
              <cac:AddressLine>
                <cbc:Line>AV. CL 80 VIA BOGOTA COTA ENT PARQUE LA FLORIDA TERRAPUERTO BG 9</cbc:Line>
              </cac:AddressLine>
              <cac:Country>
                <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                <cbc:Name languageID="es">Colombia</cbc:Name>
              </cac:Country>
            </cac:RegistrationAddress>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
              <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
              <cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
          </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
          <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>VETIPLUS S. A.</cbc:RegistrationName>
            <cbc:CompanyID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="4" schemeName="31">830026664</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cac:CorporateRegistrationScheme>
              <cbc:ID>FEL</cbc:ID>
            </cac:CorporateRegistrationScheme>
          </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
      </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
      <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
        <cac:Party>
          <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>REY LOPEZ ANA MARCELA</cbc:RegistrationName>
            <cbc:CompanyID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="8" schemeName="13">1071630658</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cbc:TaxLevelCode listName="05">O-23</cbc:TaxLevelCode>
            <cac:RegistrationAddress>
              <cbc:ID>11001</cbc:ID>
              <cbc:CityName>BOGOTÃ&#129;, D.C.</cbc:CityName>
              <cbc:PostalZone>000000</cbc:PostalZone>
              <cbc:CountrySubentity>BOGOTÃ&#129;</cbc:CountrySubentity>
              <cbc:CountrySubentityCode>11</cbc:CountrySubentityCode>
              <cac:AddressLine>
                <cbc:Line>CL 44 A SUR 78 I 10 P1</cbc:Line>
              </cac:AddressLine>
              <cac:Country>
                <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                <cbc:Name languageID="es">Colombia</cbc:Name>
              </cac:Country>
            </cac:RegistrationAddress>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
              <cbc:ID>ZY</cbc:ID>
              <cbc:Name>No causa</cbc:Name>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
          </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
          <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>REY LOPEZ ANA MARCELA</cbc:RegistrationName>
            <cbc:CompanyID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="8" schemeName="13">1071630658</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cac:CorporateRegistrationScheme>
              <cbc:CorporateRegistrationTypeCode>0001 No es obligatorio</cbc:CorporateRegistrationTypeCode>
            </cac:CorporateRegistrationScheme>
          </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        </cac:Party>
      </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
      <cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="" schemeName="">2</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>1</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
        <cbc:PaymentDueDate>2021-07-04</cbc:PaymentDueDate>
        <cbc:PaymentID>01</cbc:PaymentID>
      </cac:PaymentMeans>
      <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">1110006.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="COP">1110006.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="COP">1110006.00</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:PayableRoundingAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:PayableRoundingAmount>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="COP">1110006.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
      </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
      <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="FRASCO X 1000DS">6.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">1110000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator>false</cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
          <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
          <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">1110000.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
              <cbc:Percent>0.00</cbc:Percent>
              <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name>
              </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
          </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
          <cbc:Description>NOBILIS SG 9R X 1000 D</cbc:Description>
          <cbc:PackSizeNumeric>1.00</cbc:PackSizeNumeric>
          <cbc:AdditionalInformation>2. Detalles adicionales del producto o servicio.</cbc:AdditionalInformation>
          <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cbc:ID>148682-15</cbc:ID>
          </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
          <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="999">999</cbc:ID>
          </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
          <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">185000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
          <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="WSD">6.00</cbc:BaseQuantity>
        </cac:Price>
      </cac:InvoiceLine>
      <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="FRASCO X 200 ML">6.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">6.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator>false</cbc:FreeOfChargeIndicator>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
          <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
          <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="COP">6.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="COP">0.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
              <cbc:Percent>0.00</cbc:Percent>
              <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
                <cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name>
              </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
          </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:Item>
          <cbc:Description>NOBILIS DILUENT FD X 200 ML</cbc:Description>
          <cbc:PackSizeNumeric>1.00</cbc:PackSizeNumeric>
          <cbc:AdditionalInformation>2. Detalles adicionales del producto o servicio.</cbc:AdditionalInformation>
          <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cbc:ID>144564-10</cbc:ID>
          </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
          <cac:StandardItemIdentification>
            <cbc:ID schemeID="999">999</cbc:ID>
          </cac:StandardItemIdentification>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
          <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">1.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
          <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="WSD">6.00</cbc:BaseQuantity>
        </cac:Price>
      </cac:InvoiceLine>
    </Invoice>
```